# Get all entries attributed with category

Tags: entries, categories, relations

Maybe I'm going mad here, but I can't figure out how to get all entries which are in a certain category. 
Following the syntax laid out here: http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entries-related-to-category
you'd think something like this would work, but I get nothing:
`{% for entry in craft.entries.relatedTo('Naming') %}`

'Naming' is my category, and I have several case study entries with that category attributed.
I also tried adding more params, like restricting it to just the case study section:
`{% for entry in craft.entries.section('ourWork').relatedTo('Naming') %}`
This would be outside the category page or related case study page btw, ie on the homepage.

Answer (score 5):

Found an answer to this here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4132/3890

The important thing to note is when you're using `relatedTo` you're not passing a slug, you're passing a whole object. So just `.relatedTo('category-name')` won't work.